# Van der Waerden's classical paper on Hilbert polynomials and Bezout's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ideals, paper-request

Is it possible to obtain an electronic copy of Van der Waerden's "On Hilbert series of composition of ideals and generalisation of the Theorem of Bezout", Proceedings of the Koninklijke Akadamie van Wetenschappen Amsterdam, Vol 31, pp 749-770 (1928)? (Zentralblatt link: https://zbmath.org/54.0190.02).

It seems to have been one of the first works utilizing multigraded Hilbert polynomials. Jugal Verma says in [a survey](https://www.math.iitb.ac.in/%7Ejkv/mixed.pdf) that it is the root of the theory of mixed multiplicities of ideals. I started learning about mixed multiplicities, so thought it would be cool to start at the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried emailing Jugal? If he has a copy, that might be the quickest way to get your hands on the paper.

Comment: our library has it, I will see if I can get a copy.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, thanks - it did not occur to me. I will do that.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Thanks for your consideration, Carlo. I will write to Jugal Verma. Will let you know if he doesn't have a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just discovered that the 1928 volume of Proceedings of the Koninklijke Akadamie van Wetenschappen Amsterdam is on the "internet archive". Van der Waerden's article from the OP is in [Issue #7](https://archive.org/details/proceedings-knaw-series-b_1928_31_7/).

Edit: Francois Ziegler points out that it is also available from the  digital library of Koninklijke Akadamie van Wetenschappen [here](https://dwc.knaw.nl/toegangen/digital-library-knaw/?pagetype=publDetail&pId=PU00015633).

Comment: It's also (more predictably) at Koninklijke Nederlandse Akademie van Wetenschappen [here](//dwc.knaw.nl/toegangen/digital-library-knaw/?pagetype=publDetail&pId=PU00015633). (Sorry I missed your query the first time.)

Comment: That's great, Francois! I think it should be added to the answer ...